# Prove for every $R>0$ there's an integer $n_0>0$ such that if $n\geq n_0$ then $f_n$ has no zeroes. Using Hurwitz Theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let
$$f_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!}$$
and let
$$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}=e^z.$$ As a polynomial $f_n$ has $n$ roots in $\Bbb{C}$. Prove for every $R>0$ there's an integer $n_0>0$ such that if $n\geq n_0$ then $f_n$ has no zeroes in $B_R(0)$. So I want to appeal to Hurwitz's theorem that States if $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on every compact subset of $\Bbb{C}$ which the $f_n$ do converge uniformly to $e^z$ on every compact subset, then if $f$ has a zero at $z_0$ of order $m$ so do the $f_n$. Then since $f(z)$ has no zeroes, can I conclude the $f_n$'s have no zeroes? Or do I need to find such an $n_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $R>0.$ Since $f_n$ tends uniformly to $e^z$  on the disc $|z|\le R,$ there exists $n_0$ such that for $$|f_n(z)-e^z|< e^{-2R},\ n\ge n_0,\ |z|\le R$$
Then
$$|f_n(z)|\ge |e^z|- |f_n(z)-e^z|\\ \ge e^{-R}-e^{-2R}>0,\ n\ge n_0,\ |z|\le R$$

**Remark** No analytic function theory is needed. Almost uniform convergence to a function which does not vanish, suffices.

Comment: how'd you go from $\vert f_n(z) - e^z \vert < e^{-2R}$ to saying that its greater than or equal to $e^{-2R}$

Comment: and how does this show $f_n$'s don't have zero? on ball of radius $R$?

Comment: and I thought I had to use the fact that $e^z$ has no zeroes

Comment: $|f_n|$ is greater or equal $e^{-R}-e^{-2R}>0.$  Thus $f_n$ does not vanish for $|z|\le R$ and $n\ge n_0.$ Concerning $e^z$ we have $|e^z|=e^{{\rm Re }z}\ge e^{-R}>0.$ In particular $e^z$ dos not vanish.

Comment: also how'd you go from |()−|<−2 to saying that its greater than or equal to −2

Comment: I have used the triangle inequality$|a|\ge |b|-|a-b|.$ I didn"t claim it was greater or equal $e^{-2R}$ but greater or equal $e^{-R}-e^{-2R}.$

Comment: aha!! I just realized that after I asked it lol.

Comment: so there was no need to invoke Hurwitz Theorem?

Comment: No result from complex analysis theory is needed.  The proof is valid for any sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ convergent to a nonvanishing function $f$ almost uniformly, i.e. uniformly on bounded sets.